# How to pronounce the "n" in "wasn't really..." fast?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, american-accent

When people say "wasn't really" really fast, does the tongue position for /n/ in "wasn't" exactly the same as an usual /n/?
(like in this [description](https://pronuncian.com/pronounce-n-sound#:%7E:text=To%20create%20the%20%27n%20sound,cords%20vibrate%20while%20producing%20it.).)

I ask this question because when I try shadowing the sentence "It wasn't really a job." in this [video](https://youtu.be/mXWQD8Tyve0?t=24), I find it extremely difficult to speak at the exact same speed as Tom Hanks. If I put my tongue for the /n/ in the "proper" place (alveolar ridge), the /n/ will hinder my /r/ that follows.

Is it just a lack of practice for me or the tongue position for
/n/ deviates a little?

Comment: If I speak "wasn't really" very quickly, then the /t/ essentially disappears, but the /n/ and /r/ are still there as normal. Most native speakers don't find /nr/ to be an unusual combination - it appears in words like "unroll" or "sunrise" or the name "Henry".

Answer (score 1):

With *-n't* contractions, it can be common among native speakers to drop the 't' sound, which *should* be a stop consonant. This is increasingly common when pronouncing the 't' would make the transition to the next word difficult, which may be why you are asking specifically about pronouncing "*wasn't really*". A hard 't' sound would restrict the flow into the 'r' sound of 'really'.

Normally you would pronounce a longer 'n', followed by the 't', but when the 't' is dropped, the 'n' sound, which is a nasal consonant, stops abruptly.

Comment: By *drop the 't' sound, which should be a stop consonant*, do you mean that *there should be /t/*? Because /t/ is already a stop.

Comment: @Wistful Absolutely, the 'T' in "don't", "won't", "wasn't" etc should be pronounced. Have a listen to pronunciation guides for the word in isolation if you're not sure. But when the word is used mid-sentence then the 't' may not be sounded.

Comment: It's not that the /t/ isn't pronounced: it isn't _released_. There's still a (slight) stop in the breathflow, but there is no dental/alveolar release.

Comment: @ColinFine that doesn't fit with the definition of pronounced. If the sound isn't made in the usual or correct way then it isn't pronounced.

Comment: @Astralbee: That's not how most linguists think of "pronounced". An [unreleased stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release) is a common allophone of a stop consonant in clusters, and sometimes finally. The /t/ may sometimes disappear completely in _wasn't really_, but certainly in my speech there is an audible stop, making it different from _was'n'really_

Comment: @ColinFine As a linguist, how would you describe the part of the /t/ sound that you can hear when it is 'unreleased'? And 'silent' letters - is it wrong to say they are unpronounced?

Comment: Exactly that way, @Astralbee: as an unreleased alveolar stop. In an everyday sense of "pronounce", certainly silent letters are not pronounced. In a more technical sense, sounds are pronounced, not letters. The relationship of letters to sounds is somewhat loose, especially in English.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker but quite a proficient user of English and when I pronounce these kind of transitions I have two options of which I prefer the former (sorry):

1. The "t" sound is dropped and instead of "wasn't really" I get "wasn-really" which kind of flows as a single word. The "t' sound indeed does prevent the flow and is quite uncomfortable to pronounce.
2. The "t" sound is replaced by a really soft staccato "d" sound, which is quite close to being "t" in fact and we get "wasn'd-really" where we kind of have the stop consonant but the flow is achieved!
3. The "t" sound is pronounced and a short pause comes after.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Neither of these describes how I as a native speaker say it: there is a definite but unreleased stop [t̚] in there.